# How to expose a C++ function modifying data by reference to Python using pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pass-by-reference, pybind11

I am using pybind11 to create a Python interface to a C++ library,
one of the functions receives pointer to char array and updates its value ,
the problem is that the value of the char array is changed in C++ code but is not changed after returning from the C++ function call as shown in the next code.

```
int Copy_String::ModifyString(char* rxBuf)
{
    cout <<"***C++ Before copy***==>" << rxBuf << endl;
    strcpy(rxBuf, "Data to be copied");
    cout <<"***C++ After copy***==> "<< rxBuf << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use the following pybind11 code to expose the function to Python:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(copylib, m)
{
    m.doc() = "test modifying string passed by reference"; 
    py::class_<Copy_String>(m,"Copy_String")
        .def_static("ModifyString", &Copy_String::ModifyString," Modify String passed by reference");
}
```

and use the following python to test it

```py
import copylib as cp
class String:
    string="ABC"

obj = String()
print(obj.string)
cp.Copy_String.ModifyString(obj.string)
print(obj.string)
```

The problem is that the value of "obj.string" is received and changed inside the C++ code
but when I check it after calling the function in python I found that the initial value is not modified as shown in next code.

```
ABC
***C++ Before copy***==>ABC
***C++ After copy***==> Data to be copied
ABC
```

I found some other work around proposing to implement a c++ wrapper or passing ctype variable from python.

How to pass object by reference to c++ function from python code?

Comment: Wouldn’t that `strcpy` overrun the buffer if you *did* directly have the one for Python’s `"ABC"`?

Comment: @DavisHerring the question is not clear for me

Comment: You’re trying to copy 17 characters into a 3-character string.

Comment: @DavisHerring I think the problem is not related to the size of the data, I tested with intializing 'sring' vriable in python with  more characters than the charrachters copied inside the C++ library. but I get the same result, the data copied inside the C++ library can be displayed only inside the C++ function, but after return from the C++ call the content of 'string' is the old value used for initializing the variable in python.

Comment: That’s not the point: this style of modifying Python data can’t work usefully, so there’s no point in working out how to make it work in the limited sense in which it can.

Comment: @DavisHerring So what is the right way to modify python data from C++ function using Pybind11

Comment: Since Python strings are immutable, the task is impossible as given.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a Python string, so you have to return a **new** `str` object instead.  (You do that by copying the original string into a buffer that is then modified by the C++ function—after checking that it's *exactly* the right length!)

(Technically, from C/C++ you can modify a Python string, but not its length, and it'll break a lot of things if you use it without the utmost care.)

Answer (score 0):

For basic data types, such as `int`, `double`, `float`, you can wrap the function with reference type in a lambda function and return them.
Suppose you have a c++ function with arguments by reference as follows,

```cpp
void plus_one_inplace(int &i) { i++; }
```

you can bind it with lambda function in pybind like this

```cpp
PYBIND11_MODULE(_core, m) {
    m.def("plus_one_inplace", [](int i){plus_one_inplace(i); return i;}, "add one inplace");
}
```

and import `_core` in python

```py
import _core
i = 1
i = m.plus_one_inplace(i)
i
```

and then you will get `i=2`.

As ints are immutable types in python so you need to wrap in lambda function and return value.

Extend reference type from int to vector, you may try opaque in pybind to avoid unnecessary copy movement, here is an example to use `vector<char>` to simulate `char*`

```cpp
void concat(std::vector<char>& s1, const std::vector<char>& s2) {
    s1.insert(s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end());
}
```

then you can bind as follows

```cpp
#include<pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<char>);

PYBIND11_MODULE(_core, m) {
      py::bind_vector<std::vector<char>>(m, "VectorChar");
      m.def("concat", &concat, "s1"_a, "s2"_a);
}
```

you can import `_core` in python like this,

```py
>>> import two_center_integral as m
>>> s1 = m.VectorChar("hello")
>>> s2 = m.VectorChar("world")
>>> m.concat(s1, s2)
>>> s1
VectorChar[h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d]
>>> ''.join(s1)
'helloworld'
```

and see `s1` has been passed as reference.

Reference:

1. https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers
2. https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/134