# list passed as reference to a pybind11 wrapped function is not returned as modified in python

Tags: python, pybind11

It is likely a standard problem, but I am not finding the right path to solution on the web. A related question is [How to expose c++ function modifying data by reference to python using pybind11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72746113/how-to-expose-c-function-modifying-data-by-reference-to-python-using-pybind11), but it did not receive a general answer.

I have a function with a structure passed as reference, say:

```
some_function(auto& struct).
```

This function changes the struct, but when I use pybind11 to expose it to python, the struct is unchanged. What is the correct (and if possible simple) way to deal with this rather common issue?

PS: in my real-life situation, some_function is a method of a class, and struct is a vector of objects. Everything goes well in terms of executing some_function in python by passing a list of the objects, themselves exposed by pybind11.

Comment: Please, provide a proper [mcve] representing your specific usecase. The textual description is nice, but leaves too many ambiguities.

Comment: You are right Dan, and actually doing this exercise helped me understand the problem a bit more, and solve it at least for my concrete purpose.

Comment: Glad it helped, and I hope you understand why it was necessary to get better understanding of the problem. Without a concrete example (that's best exemplified by code) it often ends up in a guessing game with a lot of time wasted. :)

Answer (score 1):

So the generic situation is as follows :
Take a basic class A

```
class A
{
  public:
   int n=0; double val=0.;
   A(){;}
};
```

and a function B that takes an instance of A as argument and modifies its content. Expose it with a basic

```
py::class_<A>(mod, "A")
 .def(py::init<>())
 .def_readwrite("n", &A::n)
 .def_readwrite("val", &A::val)
 ;
mod.def("B", &B);
```

Then :

- If B is `inline void B(A a) {a.n=1; a.val=0.1;}` then the python sequence `a = A(); B(a); a.n,a.val` will show that the internal variables are not updated
- If B is `inline void B(A& a) {a.n=1; a.val=0.1;}` then the python sequence `a = A(); B(a); a.n,a.val` will show that the internal variables are updated

But now if B takes a list of objects A as argument, which was my situation, then :

- If B is `inline void B(vector<A>& alist) {for(auto& a : alist) {a.n=1; a.val=0.1;}}` then the internal variables in the objects of the python list are not updated
- If B is `inline void B(vector<A*> alist) {for(auto& a : alist) {a.n=1; a.val=0.1;}}` then the internal variables in the objects of the python list are updated

My question was due to being stuck with the 3rd bullet situation, and not going to the 4th one as a solution. I am not sure where I should have looked for it, I must confess that I am quickly lost when I browse the pytbind11 documentation.

Comment: OK, now that I see those last two bullet points, it starts to make sense. It's the conversion from list to vector. The first case (`vector<A>`) would imply copy by value, whereas the (`vector<A*>`) would be by reference. So in the first case, you get a vector of copies of `A` objects that were stored in the Python list. Hence any modifications on those won't propagate back. In the second scenario, you get a vector of pointers (references) to the actual objects stored in the list. Hence when you modify the vector elements, the changes propagate back to the Python list.

Comment: Frankly, in this scenario it might be better to just take the `pybind11::list` as a parameter, and work with that instead (avoiding the implicit conversion to `std::vector`). But if your current solution works for you, then great :).

Comment: I missed the pybind11::list construct. As I said, I am quickly lost in the doc. I am going to have a look at it.

Comment: Alternatively, can you provide me with a quick example of how you would change my code line above?